# How to assign a list value within pandas using slicing or other method?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a column 'Matrix', and I have a list of rows named 'after_class', and I want to assign each row's value in after_class to which the second element to 0, 
the number of row : after_class = [2, 10, 14, 17, 20, 27, 29, 33]. But as I tried, the df.loc[1, 'Matrix'] also become 0, why this happened?

```
print(df.head(11))            
print(after_class)
for n in after_class:

   df.loc[n, 'Matrix'][1] = 0
   print(n, df.loc[n, 'Matrix'])
print(df.head(11))
                   time   open   high   ...     K_Class  diff   Matrix
0   2019-01-23 18:25:00  2.420  2.421   ...          -1   NaN      NaN
1   2019-01-23 18:35:00  2.417  2.418   ...           1   2.0  [-1, 1]
2   2019-01-23 18:40:00  2.418  2.419   ...           1   0.0  [-1, 1]
3   2019-01-23 18:50:00  2.422  2.423   ...           1   0.0      NaN
4   2019-01-23 18:55:00  2.421  2.430   ...           1   0.0      NaN
5   2019-01-23 19:10:00  2.426  2.432   ...           1   0.0      NaN
6   2019-01-23 19:15:00  2.431  2.437   ...           1   0.0      NaN
7   2019-01-23 19:20:00  2.436  2.447   ...           1   0.0      NaN
8   2019-01-23 19:25:00  2.443  2.448   ...           1   0.0      NaN
9   2019-01-23 19:30:00  2.447  2.458   ...          -1  -2.0   [1, 1]
10  2019-01-23 19:40:00  2.448  2.450   ...          -1   0.0   [1, 1]


[2, 10, 14, 17, 20, 27, 29, 33]


0   2019-01-23 18:25:00  2.420  2.421   ...      NaN      NaN      NaN
1   2019-01-23 18:35:00  2.417  2.418   ...      2.0  [-1, 0]  [-1, 0]
2   2019-01-23 18:40:00  2.418  2.419   ...      0.0  [-1, 0]  [-1, 0]
3   2019-01-23 18:50:00  2.422  2.423   ...      0.0      NaN      NaN
4   2019-01-23 18:55:00  2.421  2.430   ...      0.0      NaN      NaN
5   2019-01-23 19:10:00  2.426  2.432   ...      0.0      NaN      NaN
6   2019-01-23 19:15:00  2.431  2.437   ...      0.0      NaN      NaN
7   2019-01-23 19:20:00  2.436  2.447   ...      0.0      NaN      NaN
8   2019-01-23 19:25:00  2.443  2.448   ...      0.0      NaN      NaN
9   2019-01-23 19:30:00  2.447  2.458   ...     -2.0   [1, 0]   [1, 0]
10  2019-01-23 19:40:00  2.448  2.450   ...      0.0   [1, 0]   [1, 0]
```

Comment: Show us your dataframe please

Comment: Where is your after class? What is the expected output?

Comment: I dont want any second value of row outside the after_class list to be assigned 0

Comment: I don't see any after_class in your dataframe? What is after_class after all?

Comment: My expected result is that the 9th and 1th row Matrix's second value should not be changed to 0...

Comment: using after_class what do you want the matrix column to look like? What is the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that the 1st and 2nd row matrix column element are the same object.This can be same case for the 10th and 9th element too since both are same.

As shown here in the example

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[[1,2]]]*3
row = [0,2]
print('row',row)
df = pd.DataFrame(data = data, columns=["Row-data"])

print(df)

for r in row:   
    df.loc[r,"Row-data"][1] = 0

print(df)
```

output

```
row [0, 2]
  Row-data
0   [1, 2]
1   [1, 2]
2   [1, 2]
  Row-data
0   [1, 0]
1   [1, 0]
2   [1, 0]
```

All the elements in the Row-data changed because the object in each row is the same. So if you make any changes in the object in any row, it would be reflected in the other rows where you have that same object placed.

### In order to treat them as different object (The Solution)

You can use copy library like the following

```
import pandas as pd
import copy

data = [[[1,2]]]*3
row = [0,2]
print('row',row)
df = pd.DataFrame(data = data, columns=["Row-data"])

print(df)

for r in row:
    # getting the copy of object    
    row_data = copy.deepcopy(df.loc[r,"Row-data"])
    # modifying the copy
    row_data[1] = 0
    # assigning the copy to that row
    df.loc[r,"Row-data"] = row_data

print(df)
```

Output

```
row [0, 2]
  Row-data
0   [1, 2]
1   [1, 2]
2   [1, 2]
  Row-data
0   [1, 0]
1   [1, 2]
2   [1, 0]
```

I hope this solves your problem :D

Comment: the logic here is quite weired for me, then how is the solution?

Comment: for r in row:   
    df.loc[r,"Row-data"] = '[1,0]', I have tried, using string to assign, it worked for me, but it is not pythonic at all, Atually, I would like the result where the first element to 'inherit' from the previous first element of previous row too

Comment: I would like to know how you are filling your Matrix column. Then I might be able to suggest a solution.

Comment: df.Matrix.fillna(method='ffill', axis=0, inplace=True, limit=1), I used this to fill the first nan value after any non-nan value

Comment: but I don't think this is the point, the point is how do I seperate them instead of treating them as the same object